# Why doesn't refreshing this page refresh the frame in Opera?

Tags: opera

On [this page](http://js1k.com/2010-first/demo/11) in Opera on Windows, pressing the refresh button or F5 doesn't refresh the frame with the game in. Does anyone know why?

Answer (score 1):

It's a bug. When a request for the main FRAMESET file gets a 304 Not Modified response, Opera will not re-load the frames inside. Try right-click, "Frame > Reload" instead.

Answer (score 0):

I thought so. I filed a bug report for it (DSK-320851). Would be great if it was picked up.

As it stands I rewrote the entire site to use static html, with the frames even inlined. So that effectively means Opera can't refresh any of the demo's. Kind of sucks... I was afraid it was an edge case (side effect for inlining the frames), but I guess it's not.

The alternative is to press enter in the address bar btw. That does properly refresh the frames.